# Microsoft Office Interop Excel is not closing on windows 2008 64bit and office 2007 32bit

Tags: c#, asp.net, memory-management, excel-interop

I created a excel helper class, to interact excel interop service.
But i noticed that the `excel.exe` is not getting closed on the server. 
(windows 2008 64bit Japanese OS and office 2007 32bit). 
When i checked with process explorer it shows tooltip like:

```
Path:[Error opening process]
```

I did `excel.Quit()` and `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_xlApp)` but nothing works as expected, then tried to kill the process by `processID`, still not killing the process.

```
uint processID = 0;
GetWindowThreadProcessId((IntPtr)_hWnd, out processID);
 if (processID != 0)
 {
  System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById((int)processID).Kill();
 }
```

Then i tried below both method, but it close all manually opened excel documents.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process[] procs = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL");
        foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in procs)
        {
            int baseAdd = p.MainModule.BaseAddress.ToInt32();
            if (baseAdd == _xlApp.Hinstance)
            {
                p.Kill();
            }
        }

System.Diagnostics.Process[] procs = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL");
         foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in procs)
         {
             if (p.MainWindowTitle.Length == 0)
             {
                 p.Kill();
             }
         }
```

Any idea about how to deal with this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the processId is a little bit more complicated.
Try this...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an Interop.Application object and its associated processId
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Excel.Application or Word.Application depending on _isExcel</returns>
    private object ApplicationFactory()
    {
        object application = null;
        string processName = (_isExcel) ? "excel" : "winword";
        Process[] beforeProcesses = null;
        Process[] afterProcesses = null;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 3)
        { // ourProcess = afterList - beforeList
            beforeProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
            application = (_isExcel) ? (object)new Excel.Application() : (object)new Word.Application();
            afterProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
            if ((afterProcesses.Length - beforeProcesses.Length) == 1)
            { // OK. Just a single new process
                break;
            }
            else
            { // Two or more processes, we cannot get our processId
                // therefore quit while we can and try again
                if (_isExcel)
                    ((Excel._Application)application).Quit();
                else
                    ((Word._Application)application).Quit();
                int indexReferences = 1;
                do
                {
                    indexReferences = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(application);
                }
                while (indexReferences > 0);
                application = null;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(150);
                i++;
            }
        }
        if (application == null)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Unable to create Excel Application and get its processId");
        }
        List<int> processIdList = new List<int>(afterProcesses.Length);
        foreach (Process procDesp in afterProcesses)
        {
            processIdList.Add(procDesp.Id);
        }
        foreach (Process proc in beforeProcesses)
        {
            processIdList.Remove(proc.Id);
        }
        _processId = processIdList[0];
        return application;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Kills _processId process if exists
    /// </summary>
    private void ProcessKill()
    {
        Process applicationProcess = null;
        if (_processId != 0)
        {
            try
            {
                applicationProcess = Process.GetProcessById(_processId);
                applicationProcess.Kill();
            }
            catch
            { // no Process with that processId
            }
        }
    }
```

That said, violence is just the last resourse ;-)
You need to kill because there are some COM objects not released. (See
[MS Support: Office application does not close](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=317109))
Try reference your COM objects always, put them in a Stack and release them after use with

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
```

then, a simple `application.Quit();application = null` will make the trick.

Hope it helps.

EDIT:
- Always means: "whenever you use two points (`_xlApp.Application., _xlWorkbook.Worksheets,...`)

- Add to stack means `stack.push(_xlApp.Application)`
- Release means `stack.pop()`

I include mi helperStack

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace OfficeUtils.Stack
{
/// <summary>
/// Stack of COM objects to be released
/// </summary>
public abstract class ComObjectsStack
{
    private Stack<object> comObjects = new Stack<object>();
    private int mark = 0;

    /// <summary>
    /// Releases all the remaining COM objects
    /// </summary>
    ~ComObjectsStack()
    {
        if (comObjects.Count > 0)
            ReleaseAll();
        comObjects = null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add a new object to the stack to be released
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">Nuevo objeto a liberar</param>
    public void Push(object obj)
    {
        comObjects.Push(obj);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Release the last object in the stack
    /// </summary>
    public void Pop()
    {
        Release(1);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Mark for future use of ReleaseUpToMark
    /// </summary>
    public void Mark()
    {
        mark = comObjects.Count;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Release up to mark
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Number of released objects</returns>
    public int ReleaseUpToMark()
    {
        int numberObjects = comObjects.Count - mark;
        if (numberObjects > 0)
        {
            Release(numberObjects);
            return numberObjects;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Release all the objects in the stack
    /// </summary>
    public void ReleaseAll()
    {
        if (comObjects != null)
            Release(comObjects.Count);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Release the last numberObjects objects in stack
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="numberObjects">Number of objects to release</param>
    private void Release(int numberObjects)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < numberObjects; j++)
        {
            object obj = comObjects.Pop();
            int i = 1;
            do
            {
                i = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            }
            while (i > 0);
            obj = null;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: hi, @raist thank you very much for your comments. Seems to be a good approach. let me try this and will update you.

Answer (score 1):

I found by using the following I was able to remove Excel from the task manager:

```
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

    /// <summary>
    /// Excel application
    /// </summary>
    private ApplicationClass m_xlApp = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Reference to the workbook.
    /// </summary>
    private Workbook m_book = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Reference to the worksheet.
    /// </summary>
    private Worksheet m_sheet = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Close the workbook.
    /// </summary>
    public void Close()
    {
        if (m_book != null)
            m_book.Close(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

        if (m_xlApp != null)
        {
            m_xlApp.Workbooks.Close();
            m_xlApp.Quit();
        }

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        // Release the objects
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(m_sheet);
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(m_book);
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(m_xlApp);

        m_sheet = null;
        m_book = null;
        m_xlApp = null;
    }
```